# Why does this MySQL query return twice?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables which I'm joining into one by this query:

```
SELECT priorities.zadano, priorities.popis, priorities.deadline, priorities.dokonceno, priorities.priorita, priorities.honorar, priorities.zaplaceno, priorities.client_FK, clients.id, clients.jmeno
FROM priorities, clients, firma
WHERE priorities.client_FK=clients.id
```

But as you can see in the picture below, it's returning twice the same thing. Why?

[image: my phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the firma table and it'll work ok.

```
SELECT priorities.zadano, priorities.popis, priorities.deadline, priorities.dokonceno, priorities.priorita, priorities.honorar, priorities.zaplaceno, priorities.client_FK, clients.id, clients.jmeno
FROM priorities, clients  
WHERE priorities.client_FK=clients.id
```

You probably have 2 records in that table and it's doing a natural join on it.

Comment: oh, great, thanks, didn't notice it. stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that you must use a "Group By" on this case.